# About the corvergence of series involving Stirling numbers of first kind and number theoretic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, stirling-numbers

One knows the Wikipedia article, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), and the MathWorld article, [thisone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html) dedicated to the Stirling numbers of the first kind. I've denoted $S^{k}(n)=s(n,k)$ as the signed Stirling numbers of first kind and thus $|s(n,k)|=\begin{bmatrix}n\\k\\\end{bmatrix}$ are the unsigned numbers, where $|x|$ is the absolute value of $x$.

In the recent past I did more experiments with the help of [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com), and I wondered if some of my experiments/claims can be proved as right or wrong. My experiments were involving these sequence of numbers and number theoretic functions.

**I need an example** to know how work with these series, because I don't know how to combine the asymptotic of Stirling numbers of first kind to deduce the convergence of my series.

**Experiment 1.** I believe that the following series involving signed Stirling numbers of first kind $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{S^{(\varphi(n))}_n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{s(n,\varphi(n))}{n!}\tag{1}$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{S^{(\pi(n))}_n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{s(n,\pi(n))}{n!}\tag{2}$$
are convergent series, where $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function and $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function. (If I remember well the same claims should be true with unsigned numbers $|s(n,k)|$ instead of $s(n,k)$ in previous series).$\square$

**Experiment 2.** Here I wanted to search a different combination, now involving in the summation the arithmetic function $\mu(n)$, the so-called Möbius function. It is an erratic function famous because is involved also in unsolved problems. I believe that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^n S^{(m)}_n m^{1+\delta}\mu(m)\tag{3}$$
converges if $\delta=0$ and doesn't converge for each $\delta>0$.

This was

`sum  StirlingS1[n, m] m mu(m)/n!, from m=1 to n, from n=1 to 300`

the code for this last experiment.$\square$

> **Question.** Prove or refute the convergence of one of previous examples, to know how works with this kind of series. **Many thanks.**

Only is required an example with details/hints to deduce your result.

Of course with my scarced experiments and knowledges I don't know if my series are the more interesting for which one can ask*.

I wanted write this post as companion of a previous that I've asked (see [1]), being answered with a great answer.

### References:

[1] [*Does* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}{n\brace \varphi(n)}$ *converge, where* ${n\brace m}$ *are Stirling numbers of second kind?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331498/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nn-brace-varphin-converge-where-n-br), from this Mathematics Stack Exchange (2017).

Comment: *Feel free, in comments, to criticize or add some remarks if it is possible to improve or expand some of my creations Experiment 1/Experiment 2. I have no a good intutition if my series have a good mathematical meaning (if these are obvious or difficult to prove from the asymptotic of the Stirling numbers). Many thanks.